# Is it appropriate to ask "dumb" questions.

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

As I found, most people asking really smart questions. But what if I have a "dumb" question. When I simply don't understand something or even don't understand some answers. More specifically, can I ask a question about an answer posted on math.stackexchange.com?

Or is there an appropriate place where I can ask that sort of questions?

Comment: This is related to one part of your question: [Clarify an old answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/clarify-an-old-answer).

Comment: I suggested to some of my (junior honours) students that they could ask some of their questions on here. They didn't want too, claiming they the level of questions here were "too high". So, I think this is a common worry...

Comment: @user1729 That was a year ago... I think the problem of having *too high* level of questions appears to be resolving itself. That said, I could not resist [doing this](http://qkme.me/3ubls0).

Comment: @75064 This comment may be a year old, but the (different) students I have been interacting with this year hold the same opinion.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The charter of MSE is to welcome *all* types of *mathematical* questions. In particular, we do not discriminate based on the "level" of the question. But we do frown upon poorly posed questions - whatever the level. Please provide as much context as possible when posing your question. Tell us something about what fields of math that you know (and/or put this info in your profile). Mention the source of the problem and and/or your motivation for solving it. Tell us what you have tried and where you are stuck. The more information that you supply the better we can provide you with answers that are aimed precisely at your level.

Comment: I was just teaching a class and somebody wrote on the white board among other rules "There are no dumb questions-please try not to disprove this"

Comment: @Ross: I would prefer the wording "Please do not try to disprove this."  Actively trying not to disprove it is too much pressure.

Answer (score 35):

There is no lower bound on how "dumb" a question can be here. We only ask that you've put some honest effort into it (e.g. that you don't ask a question about a homework problem you don't understand when you haven't even looked up the words in it yet).

Answer (score 5):

Adding to what has been already stated, if it is the case that your question merely requires a "moment" of thought and a little determination for resolution, then please do refrain from posting for lack of initiative on (potentially) your part.

Although, this may go without saying, such criterion makes explicit the point of *effort* in mathematics. So, it's not really there for our benefit as much as it is for *yours*. Though it may seem to the contrary, every great mathematician (or great anything) was the result of a lifetime of determined effort, which is a principle one must always strive to uphold in all endeavors.